# Knative's support for the Socket protocol

Tags: kubernetes, serverless, knative

Our business requires deploying a socket server on Knative Serving and providing a fixed IP for socket connection to clients outside the cluster. However, Knative is designed for HTTP connections, and currently, I haven't found any information about Knative Serving exposing services via sockets or transport layer protocols. Is there any method available at the moment to expose a service in Knative Serving to the outside cluster using socket communication?

I have now attempted to deploy a Socket server and a client within Knative Serving, and communication is functioning properly using the cluster's internal IP. However, I am unsure of how to establish a connection with clients outside the cluster.